# Decompose website into rectangular grid?

Tags: image-processing, web-access

I'd like to take an image of a website and decompose it into a rectangular clustering of dominant pixels like this:

[image]

**What I've tried so far**

There are a few existing webpage segmentation solutions:

- https://github.com/nik0spapp/sdalg
- https://github.com/asanoja/web-segmentation-evaluation

But these work on raw HTML/CSS. I believe there should be a way to *segment a website's image*, perhaps splitting into a grid. One way to approach this might be to choose the horizontal/vertical splits first and recursing:

```
i = CloudGet[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/c563ac00-67f5-4a1a-b086-8aa7acfa8fe8"];
ga = GradientFilter[i, {{1, 50}}] // ImageAdjust;
Row[{i, ga}]
```

[image]

```
id = ImageDimensions[i];
rows = id[[2]] - Ordering[Total /@ ImageData[ga], -3] // N;
HighlightImage[i, Rectangle[{0, # - 1}, {id[[1]], # + 1}] & /@ rows]
```

[image]

But this is brittle. So I'm looking for a more robust way of doing this operation. Some ideas:

- Leveraging the divs in the DOM structure (as @CarlLange has pointed out)
- Using a morphological filter and look for rectangular components
- Somehow use the masks from `DominantColor`
- Use `WebSessionObject`s and compute the divs with javascript?

This is a tough high-level algorithmic problem that may admit many interesting solutions, so please don't downvote simply because it is broad.

Comment: A somewhat plausible method would be to decompose the HTML into its largest _n_ divs, then get the dominant color of each div. However, you'd need to render the page before you can do that, since the size of divs is more CSS than content nowadays. So it may be easier or more plausible to do some image processing on a screenshot of the page instead.

Comment: Divs aren’t always visible, a typical html page has tons of non-visual cruft

Comment: I agree and am just trying to help start a discussion, since the question seems quite broad. Apologies if that's not useful to you.

Comment: No apology needed! I realize this is a broad question... anything helps

Comment: Reads like a gimmedacodez question to me.

Comment: Sure but it is interesting

Comment: @CarlLange I think your way is probably the best route, I'm playing with WebExecute functions now...